# Postgres Session data on exception

Tags: postgresql, exception

I have a session variable in postgres.conf file, user.user_id = 0. I am setting it to 1234 using `set_config('user.user_id', '1234'::text, FALSE)`

The problem is when I use RAISE EXCEPTION, or if there is any EXCEPTION in the code the value of `current_setting('user.user_id')` is being returned as 0 (value is reset), I tried even using a temporary table and storing the session data user.user_id in the table, I am loosing even the TEMP table on exception (Getting error: relation does not exist ), My understanding is on EXCEPTION the session data is lost. Am I right ? Is there a way to solve this, to retain the session data in some other way on exception.

Please advice.

Comment: Do you close the database session when you get an exception? That would explain what you see.

Comment: No i am not closing the session.

Answer (score 0):

First I'm going to assume that you mean postgresql.conf not postgres.conf. Second those settings are global. You made it session specific by using set_config:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET

"set_config sets the parameter setting_name to new_value. If is_local is true, the new value will only apply to the current transaction. If you want the new value to apply for the current session, use false instead. "

TEMP tables are also session/transaction specific depending how they are created. If you want to retain that information you will need to store it in a permanent table. At that point I would probably get rid of the postgresql.conf setting, one less thing to carry over on version upgrade.

Comment: Regarding the permanent table solution that you provided, the problem is on exception even the inserts in the permanent table are lost. Is there a way I can save the insert on that particular table and let the other transactions go away on the exception.

Comment: You have not said where you are raising EXCEPTION. If it is a plpgsql function then take a look at: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING. Otherwise you will need to give a complete example of what you are doing.